# SUM in SQL returning incorrect amount

Tags: select, sum, ssms, where-clause

This will seem incredibly simple but I can't figure out why the following query is returning an incorrect number.

I have put the data set into excel and done the calculations just to verify. The sum of m1 is 36785. When I remove areas 900 and 995. It comes to 18653. From looking at this query, what is the flaw? If I leave the () off it, the value calculated is 1716093. The query as shown below returns a value of 36785.

```
select sum(m1)
from dbo.sizeclassreportgov
where own='10' and (area !='900' or area != '995');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for will be:

```
select sum(m1)
from dbo.sizeclassreportgov
where own='10' and area not in ('900', '995');
```

`area !='900' or area != '995'` will always evaluate to true (unless `area` is `NULL`).

(If `area` does contain any `NULL` values, you'd need to use `(area not in ('900', '995') or area is null)`.)

Comment: why will area !='900' or area != '995' always evaluate to true?

Comment: It's because it's an `OR` condition, so either condition will do for a true evaluation. `'900' != '995'`, so `'900'` will still return true. If you took away the parentheses and just made it an `AND` rather than an `OR`, that would work too.